# Monte Carlo RL - why is the computational expense of estimating the value of a single state is independent of the number of states?

Tags: machine-learning

In [Sutton's book on RL](http://people.inf.elte.hu/lorincz/Files/RL_2006/SuttonBook.pdf), under Monte Carlo policy evaluation, he mentions on page 111 that `note that the computational expense of estimating the value of a single state is independent of the number of states`. However, since for Monte Carlo:

- The average return for a state is calculated from when the state is first encountered until the end of the episode
- The more states there are, the more likely the end of the episode takes longer to reach

So what am I missing about that statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`An important fact about Monte Carlo methods is that the estimates for
each state are independent.`

If each state is calculated independently, then it should clearly follow that it doesn't matter how many different states are possible when you're determining a state-value estimate for a single state. It's *because* of this independent nature that MC systems are useful.

I believe you're getting mixed up with the fact that large state systems will take OVERALL longer to compute (the entire system), but since the probability of winning with a 17 doesn't affect winning with an 18 these states don't depend on each other.

edit:
I think there's a stats or ML stackoverflow page that this question might be better directed towards as well.

Comment: Thanks! I know there's data exchange but question rarely gets answered there. So his statement in the book makes sense in the context of comparison to DP, which requires the estimates for neighboring states to be available before update to current state can be done.